# Is there a way to tag specs2 tests in Scala?

Tags: scala, specs2

I want to tag my Scala specs2 tests . But all examples i found on web seems to be outdated . My Scala version is 2.11.8 and 2.11

Comment: Tagging hasn't really changed, so this isn't asking anything new. If you have a specific setup that isn't working, please explain it in more detail with an example so that someone can help fix a specific problem you may be having.

Comment: I am writing my tests in below format  :
class MySpec extends Specification with Mockito{    class Actors extends TestKit(ActorSystem("test")) with ImplicitSender with Scope
 tag("mytag")   “My test is supposed to do this in new Actors {
//test code

}
}

But the activator commands did not work to include/exclude the tagged test